# Jquery not delaying properly when clicking on <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, delay

I have a div I want to show when I click an `<a>` tag, I want to wait for like 10 seconds before redirecting, but it just shows me the div and redirects without waiting.

Html code:

```
<a class="clickHereToDisplay" href="http://www.google.com">Click here to go</a>"
 <div class="hiddenDiv"></div>
```

Jquery code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
window.setTimeout(function(){

$(".clickHereToDisplay").click(function(){
   $('.hiddenDiv').text('THE TEXT I WANT TO DISPLAY WHEN THE HREF IS CLICKED');
   $('.hiddenDiv').show();
     });
  }),10000;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the browser is using the href to immediately redirect.  You want something like this:

```
<a class="clickHereToDisplay" href="#" onclick="timedRedirect()">Click here to go</a>"
<div class="hiddenDiv"></div>
```

Then your javascript:

```
var timedRedirect = function() {
    $('.hiddenDiv').text('THE TEXT I WANT TO DISPLAY WHEN THE HREF IS CLICKED');
    $('.hiddenDiv').show();
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = "http://www.google.com"
    }),10000);
};
```

One other note; there is nothing preventing the user from doing other stuff in the ensuing 10 seconds, so make sure you handle user flows you don't want occurring (like other event handlers, etc).

Comment: The key was what you said about the href(href="#").

    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  window.setTimeout(function(){
    $(".clickHereToReset").click(function(){
       $('.hiddenDiv').text('testssssssssssssdffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffssssssssssss');
        $('.hiddenDiv').show(1000000);
        var url = "http://www.google.com";
        var delay = 3000;
        setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = url;
        }, delay);
    });
  });
});
</script>

This is the improved and working script.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the timeout in the click handler.

In the click handler first you need to show the hidden div and the use a timer to delay the redirection for which you need to prevent the default action of the click and then manually set the location in the timeout handler.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".clickHereToDisplay").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.hiddenDiv').text('THE TEXT I WANT TO DISPLAY WHEN THE HREF IS CLICKED').show();
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            window.location = e.currentTarget.href;
        }, 10000);
    });
});
```